# Can I write to a vector in an interrupt, and then read within main thread only, in a safe way?

Tags: c++, serial-port, embedded, interrupt, c++98

I need a structure for my interrupt where I store the chars coming in through the communication channel to some sort of storage in mbed. I have tried to do that within ISR-safe queue, but it might be the reason behind my ISR not catching up with what's coming through.

What I would like to know is if I can `push_back()` a char within an interrupt, and this will be the only interrupt so it will be allowed to execute fully before terminating.

In `main`, I will then check if vector is not empty and then read the char at the front if it isn't:

```
while (charThrough == 0) {
     if (myVect.size() > 0) {
         getChar = myvector.front();
         charThrough = 1;
     }
}
```

within a function which I will call to get a character out of the vector, which would return `charThrough` in `main()`.

Comment: I'ld do that with a circular buffer: https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/4/6/circular-buffers-in-cc

Comment: Bluntly: if you need to ask this question, you should port all your code to C asap. If you don't understand why, then find a vector::push_back or similar and disassemble it, then look at the machine code generated.

Comment: @ThomasG. I settled on buffered serial instead of trying to do this with vectors, but I am guessing circular buffer could have also done it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this isn't some kind of PC in disguise, but an actual embedded system:

You should not use standard library containers inside ISRs. Never. Not so much because of re-entrancy reasons, but because of performance. Nor should you have anything close to resembling template programming anywhere near your ISRs or other hardware-related code.

You shouldn't use `std::vector` at all in most embedded systems, `std::array` is preferred. Nor should you be using heap allocation.

If you for some reason must use standard library containers, you need to keep them far away from any hardware-related code. For example you could let your HAL work with such containers, but the actual drivers need to work with raw arrays.

Also avoid declaring objects from standard library classes with static storage duration,  since those will slow down your program start-up massively.

Comment: Sometimes you don't mind the tradeoff of a slow startup if it speeds up later execution. All depends on the use case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Start-up time is often critical in embedded systems. _Lots_ of quacks run all C++ constructors on the default RC oscillator, before setting PLL or switching to the internal one. Or worse, before setting up the wdog.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that it is, but sweeping generalisations are _always_ to be avoided!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, not at all. Most people writing C++ for embedded are either PC programmers who don't have a clue about hardware, or electrical engineers who don't have a clue about programming. You need to give these kind of people absolute rules or they _will_ write utter trash. They can tweak those rules when they have 10+ years of branch experience - until then, fall in line.

Comment: I don't need to "fall in line" and there's no need for the condescension. You're not the only person who's worked in embedded or who "has a clue about programming".... sigh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not directed to you personally, sorry if it came across like that. But to the Arduino hordes.

Answer (score 1):

The others are correct do not you a lot of code in interrupts and do no use dynamic allocating containers on embedded devices in general. Now onto something that might help you.

In the case your microchip has the option to use Direct Memory Access (DMA) like a lot of STM32 chips you can do something similar without any software interrupts. DMA can be coupled through hardware to your peripheral receiving data. You set up the DMA such that it will write data to a plain array. Before starting the read operation you pass a pointer to the DMA where it should write to and how much space there is in the buffer. Only once the buffer is full you will get an interrupt from the DMA it is done.

If you would like to continue reading but need to process the already received data you can have multiple buffers. Each time in the interrupt you give the DMA a pointer to next buffer and flag the previous one as ready for processing. When done with processing you flag the buffer as empty.

Side note: You could look into using `std::array` on embedded targets but these days a normal array is already very easy to use with the for-range loops.